# Initialise CATransition duration with NSNumber

Tags: ios, nsnumber, nstimeinterval, catransition

I want to initialise the duration of a `CATransition` with a `NSNumber`, how do i do this, since the `animation.duration` is a `NSTimeInterval` object?

```
- (void)startPopUpAnimation:(NSNumber *)numbers {

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.duration = @"2.15";//[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[numbers doubleValue]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than i thought:

`animation.duration` is a `typedef double` so i just did: `animation.duration = [numbers doubleValue];`